# How do I save a password hash so I can match an already hashed password?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-3.x

I am implementing a "remember me" feature (CakePHP 3) that stores username and a hashed password in a cookie. My problem is that I am not successful in matching the hashed password in the cookie with the hashed password in the database.

I am using the DefaultPasswordHasher to generate both the database hash and the cookie hash. I initially thought these would match, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

My second thought was that the DefaultPasswordHasher would have a function that could verify that both hashes came from the same password, but its check() function takes a plain text password: https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Auth.DefaultPasswordHasher.html

Similar questions online all seem to apply to older versions of Cake or are inconclusive.

From the User entity:

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
  if (strlen($password) > 0) {
    return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
  }
}
```

From the UsersController login() function

```
// Remember login?
if ($this->request->getData()['remember_me'] == "true") {
  // Hash the user's password
  $savedUser = [
    'password' => (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($this->request->getData()['password']),
    'username' => $this->request->getData()['username']
  ]; 
  // Save login for 1 month
  $result = $this->Cookie->write('cookie_name', $savedUser, true, '1 month');
}
```

From the AppController initialize() function:

```
// Load logged in user
$loggedInUserID = $this->Auth->user('id');

// If not logged in try cookie
if( !$loggedInUserID && $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('cookie_name') ) {
    error_log("Attempting to log in from cookie. Username: ".$cookie['username']);
    $user = $this->Users->find('all', [
        'conditions' => [
            'username' => $cookie['username'],
            'password' => $cookie['password'],
            'is_deleted' => 0
        ]
    ])
    ->first();

    // If a user was found, try to login
    if ($user) {
        if($this->Auth->login($user)) {
            error_log("Successfully logged in from cookie. Username: ".$cookie['username']);
            $loggedInUserID = $this->Auth->user('id');
        } else {
            error_log("Couldn't log in from cookie. Username: ".$cookie['username']);
            $this->redirect('/users/logout'); // destroy session & cookie
        }
    }
}
```

(I kept my temporary error log messages for clarity.)

The cookie seems to be saved correctly, but its hash does not match the database, which means a user matching the cookie is never found.

Is the problem that the two hashes should match? Or should I be using a function to match the two hashes with each other?

Comment: Hashes are usually salted, otherwise the password hashes of users with the same password are easily identifiable; that is a security weakness. However, I think the cookie hash doesn't match because that's not its purpose. I think the cookie hash prevents browser attackers from retrieving passwords from user cookies. Maybe the client should simply convert the hash back to the password string and send that to the `check()` method?

Comment: You can look into [Passwordable behavior](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/docs/Behavior/Passwordable.md) which provides a check against "current password" in a DRY way based on your config.
If you are not using the new auth plugins yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, you may want to have a look at the new authentication plugin, it ships with a cookie authenticator out of the box!

**https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/**

That being said, your premise is wrong, the fact that the two hashes do not match is by design, and the correct behavior, and there is no method that could match them.

What you should do, is store a unique identifier in your cookie, let's say the username, alongside a hash that is built from a second credential, a hash which you need to be able to build again when trying to login via the cookie data. Let's say for example a hash of the username + the hashed password, the *hashed* password because you need that exact value again to recreate the plain value in order to compare it against the hash stored in the cookie, ie you cannot (and should not anyways) use the plain password, as it wouldn't be available anymore on subsequent requests.

Then when using the cookie data for logging in, use the unique identifier (username) to query the user, and compare the plain value (username + hashed password) to the cookie hash via the password hasher's `check()` method.

With your given example that could look something like this (disclaimer, this is untested example code):

```php
$user = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));

$savedUser = [
    'username' => $user->username,
    'token' => (new DefaultPasswordHasher())->hash(
        $user->username . ':' . $user->password
    ),
];

// ...
```

That queries and uses the currently logged in user, so you have to do this after invoking `$this->Auth->identify()`!

```php
// ...

$user = $this->Users
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'username' => $cookie['username'],
        'is_deleted' => 0,
    ])
    ->first();

if ($user) {
    $plain = $user->username . ':' . $user->password;
    if ((new DefaultPasswordHasher())->check($plain, $cookie['token'])) {
        // the hash matches, log the user in
        $user = $user->toArray();
        unset($user['password']); // but do not put the password in the session
        $this->Auth->setUser($user);
    } else {
        // the hash doesn't match, do something else
    }
}
```

Note the use of `setUser()`, there is no `login()` method in the CakePHP 3.x `AuthComponent`, the `login()` method is from CakePHP 2.x! Also ideally you'd handle all this in a custom authentication object, and an event handler for the `Auth.afterIdentify` event, and keep the logic out of the controller.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > AuthComponent > Manually Logging Users In](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#manually-logging-users-in)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > AuthComponent > Creating Custom Authentication Objects](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects)**

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer! I had a feeling it was something along those lines but I didn't quite understand the flow. I think the only problems with your suggested code I found was that you used + instead of a dot to concatenate. And I think also $user->username should be an array element instead: $user['username']

Comment: Oops, yeah, it should be a dot. The object access should be fine though unless you'd disable hydration, array access works too as entities implement `\ArrayAccess`. @Simon